# Как сделать что бы данная функция при докрутке срабатывала только один раз?

Tags: jquery

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
        var trigger = jQuery('.animated').offset().top -500;
        if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > trigger) {             
            $('.nm').each(function() {
            $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
                Counter: $(this).text()
                }, {
                    duration: 2000,
                    easing: 'swing',             
                    step: function(now) {
                        $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
                        return false;
                    },
                });
            });
        } else {}
    });
```

Comment: По сути подойдёт любой скрипт, который по докрутке до этого блока в мобильной версии, запустит один раз "Счетчик для подсчета до целевого числа" в этом блоке https://c2n.me/4hqFYD5 . В десктопе там по наведению стоит сейчас, а в мобилках стоит по докрутке, до повторяется бесчётное количество раз из за чего работает некорректно.  Архив со страничкой: https://dropmefiles.com/yD9gL